# Derivative of $f(x) =\arccos(x \tan x)$

Tags: calculus, derivatives, solution-verification

This is what I got from it.

$\arccos y = x$

$\cos x = x\tan x$

$x = \cos x*\cot x$

then

$\arccos(\cos x*\cot x*\tan x)$

$\arccos(\cos x)= x$

$f'(x) = 1$

wolfram alpha gives me something different.

Comment: first observation... you can not use same $x$ for $f(x)$ and for $\cos^{-1} y=x$ That could be first reason for your error..

Comment: Apply chain rule directly

Comment: Apparently OP is assuming the derivative of arccos is not known at first, and used implicit differentiation.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** You should use the [chain rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_rule):
$$(g(h(x)))'=g'(h(x))h'(x)$$
For $g(x)=\arccos(x)$ and $h(x)=x\tan x$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $y = \arccos(x \tan x)$.
$$\begin{align*}
\cos y =& x \tan x\\
-\sin y \frac{dy}{dx} =& x\sec^2x +\tan x\\
\frac{d}{dx}f(x) = \frac{dy}{dx} =& -\frac{x\sec^2x +\tan x}{\sin[\arccos(x\tan x)]}
\end{align*}$$